# Unexpected result while calculation geometric series sum

Tags: geometric-series

I have a geometric series like this :

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a^{-n}e^{-jwn}$$

When I make $m = -n$ substituion, it becomes this : 
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(ae^{jw})^m$$

And when I calculate summation, the result becomes : 
$ae^{jw}/(1-ae{^jw})$

I can't understand why we end up with this result. I know that geometric series solution is this :

[image]

But when I apply this formula, I can't find this result. How do we calculate the **nominator** of the result as **ae^jw** ? **a** and **w** are constants and **j** is the **imaginary number, namely square root of -1**  Thanks.

Comment: What is known about $a$ and $w$? I suppose $j=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\mathrm i\pi}3}$?

Comment: @Bernard updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: The formula you need is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n=\frac{r}{1-r}$

Comment: @GregoryGrant what is wrong with the formula I have? It's a general one and should work with this too. Thanks for the edits btw.

Comment: It works with your formula, you need to plug in $m=1$ and then take the limit $b\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Jason: the imaginary root of $-1$ is denoted by $\mathrm i$, except by physicists (because is used to denote electric current).

Comment: It just better be that $|ae^{jw}|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{b\to+\infty}r^{b+1}=0$ if $\lvert r\rvert<1$, we have:
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^br^k=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{r-r^{b+1}}{1-r}=\frac r{1-r}. $$

Comment: You have yet to show that $|ae^{jw}|<1$.

Comment: @Demosthens: I only posted a sketch to help first, not a complete solution.